# Cant click on heads up notifications on Lollipop Nexus 5

Tags: notifications, 5.0-lollipop

I installed android lollipop from the factory images on googles website. I dont know if its supposed to be like this but i think not.

I cant click on the options in the notifications be it to answer a call or reply to an SMS.

I have to first swipe it right or left then go to the call or sms to continue.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue around here. I found that waiting for the notification to go by itself is better than Swiping right since you can still access the notification on the drawer and go directly where you need to.